# How can I print the number of unique elements instead of show the elements itself in my code?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, unique, function-definition

I want to print the number of unique elements instead of show the elements For example show 4. Means we have 4 unique elements

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 100

int ifexists(int z[], int u, int v)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<u;i++)
        if (z[i]==v) return (1);
    return (0);
}

void main()
{
    int p[max], q[max];
    int m;
    int i,k;
    k=0;
    printf("Enter length of the array:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter %d elements of the array\n",m);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++ )
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);
    q[0]=p[0];
    k=1;
    for (i=1;i<m;i++)
    {
        if(!ifexists(q,k,p[i]))
        {
            q[k]=p[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe unique elements in the array are:\n");
    for(i = 0;i<k;i++)
        printf("%d\n",q[i]);
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/Bk3tvQMpw

Comment: why cant you just paste the code here?

Comment: Just remove the final for loop and print k instead, no ?

Comment: `k` is the counter for unique elemets, right? print it.

Comment: Yes just print number of unique numbers

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array then iterate through the elements and print out if the current element is different than the last:

```
int cmpint(const void *a, const void *b) {
   return *(int *) a) < *(int *) b :
      -1 ?
      (
        *(int *) b) < *(int *) a ?
        1 :
        0
      );
}


int main() {
  /* ... */
  qsort(p, m, sizeof(*p), cmpint);

  int n = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    if(!i || p[i-1] != p[i]) n++;
  }
  printf("Number of unique elements: %d\n", n);
}
```

where p is your now sorted array and length is m as per example code.  As qsort is expected O(m *log(m)) so will this aglorithm.  If you don't sort the array it will be O(m^2) due to m linear searches.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly what you need is to count unique elements in an array using a function and without defining an auxiliary array. That is there is no need to output the unique elements themselves.

In this case the corresponding function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_unique( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    while ( n != 0 && a[ n - 1 ] != value ) --n;
    
    return n == 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    size_t count = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        count += is_unique( a, count, a[i] );
    }
    
    printf( "There are %zu unique elements in the array.\n", count );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
There are 3 unique elements in the array.
```

If you do not want to define one more function to count unique elements in an array then just move the loop in the function shown in the above demonstrative program inside main.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    size_t count = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = i;
        
        while ( j != 0 && a[j - 1] != a[i] ) --j;
        
        count += j == 0;
    }
    
    printf( "There are %zu unique elements in the array.\n", count );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above that is

```
There are 3 unique elements in the array.
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

instead of

```
void main()
```